# How can I use one template in handlebars.js, while using several objects inside?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm fairly new to handlebars.js. I'm trying to use one template to create multiple HTML items by using several objects.

This is the code I have so far:

HTML structure:

```
  <div id="homeList" style="text-align: center;">
    
  </div>


      
<script id="bar-item" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 

{{#each this}}

{{#product}}

    <div class="homeItem">
          <article class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={{thumbImg}}>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{description}}</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">More Info</button>
            </div>
          </article>
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{title}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="modal-description">{{modalDesc}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/product}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

The JavaScript

```
<script>
    var template = document.getElementById('bar-item').innerHTML;
    var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
    var context = [{
        product: [{name: "ROG Strix G731GU", 
                     description: "Hello there 01",
                    thumbImg: "https://i.ibb.co/WPtzVv8/ROG.png",
                  modalDesc: "Description1"},

                   {name: "Dell G5",
                   description: "Hello there 02",
                    thumbImg: "https://pisces.bbystatic.com/image2/BestBuy_US/images/products/6407/6407991_rd.jpg",
                   modalDesc: "Description2"}]
    }];
    var html = templateScript(context);
    document.getElementById("homeList").innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

The problem is, when accessing the `modalDesc`, it shows "Description1" in both of the modals. However, all of the other expressions are correct. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this? I have tried changing the structure of the data, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For your modules you have to use {{#each}}. Do something like this:

```
 {{#each modalDesc}}
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="modal-description">{{this.modalDesc}}</div>
   </div>
 {{/each}}
```

What this does is kind of like a javascript forEach. It uses handlebars {{each}} and will generate the html for every modaldesc you have.

Comment: Thanks Nick. However, when I try this code the descriptions are not visible. Any idea what may be wrong here?

Comment: @LesterGrillard is just the div visible or is nothing visible?

Comment: The modal is visible when the button is clicked, but none of the descriptions are shown in it. It is blank.

Comment: @LesterGrillard but when you click the button can you see the div background?

Comment: No I cannot see the div background. 
Should I do something about my outer #each loop?

Comment: Yeah I realized that could be affecting this. modalDesc. try {{../this.modalDesc}}. If that doesn't work try: `{{each modalDesc}}{{this}}{{/each}}`

Comment: That doesn't work sadly. Is there any way I can edit the outer loops to fix this problem?

Comment: try new edit. Thats really the last solution I have

Comment: I just tried, and it produces the same blank modal.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I had to dynamically display errors and I did my original solution. The problem is probably caused because you use `{{each this}}` near the top of the file. Also what does {{each this}} do in your code?

Comment: This may help btw https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader/issues/124

Comment: If I remove the each, do you think it will function by using just the #product?

Comment: Nothing is being displayed in the #each modalDesc by the way

Comment: Yes you should do {{each product}}. Then try my original solution

Comment: I managed to solve it by using the exact solution at this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452371/how-to-toggle-hide-show-inside-the-handlebars-template"

Comment: It was a problem with the repetitive ID's that were being created. I just had to add the index to the end of each id.

Comment: Nice! I’m sorry I wasn’t able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring because all the modals had the same id. In order to fix this problem, I added `-{{@index}}` to the end of the id, to create the modal. This will get the index in the current loop, and add it to the id.

Example:

```
id = "exampleId-{{@index}}"
```

The above code would set the id to something like:

```
id = "exampleId-0"
```

Or something similar, depending on the index.